# CDK: Set the "data points to alarm" parameter for a target tracking scaling policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have an ECS Fargate service with autoscaling setup to track a custom metric. How do I set the "datapoints to alarm" parameter for a target tracking autoscaling policy? I don't see it in the docs anywhere for CDK v2. This is how I've defined the scaling with a custom metric:

```
declare const fargate: FargateService;
const scaling: ScalableTaskCount = fargate.service.autoScaleTaskCount({ 
  minCapacity: 5, 
  maxCapacity: 30
})
scaling.scaleToTrackCustomMetric(`QueueSizeScaling`, {
  metric,
  targetValue: props.itemsPerInstance,
  policyName: '10k-items-per-task',
  disableScaleIn: false,
  scaleOutCooldown: Duration.minutes(2),
  scaleInCooldown: Duration.minutes(2)
});
```

I can see it as an editable option in the console but can't find where to set this in CDK.:

[image: dashboard view to edit desired parameter]

If this is not possible/advisable for some reason (as I understand target tracking scaling is meant to be a managed action) is it sound to reduce the desired task count and then stop the ECS task from within the task itself or are there drawbacks to this? When doing that, does the order of aws-sdk calls matters so make a call to `update_service` first then `stop_task` or maybe `asg.terminate_instance_in_auto_scaling_group`, or vice-versa?

EDIT#1:

My scaling metric is defined like this:

```
const metric = new cloudwatch.Metric({
  namespace: "redisQueueSizeNamespace",
  metricName: `QueueSize`,
  period: Duration.minutes(1),
  statistic: cloudwatch.Statistic.MAXIMUM,
});
```

Where a lambda continuously publishes the queue size:

```
await cloudwatch.putMetricData({
  MetricData: [
    {
      MetricName: `QueueSize`,
      Value: Number(count)
    }
  ],
  Namespace: 'redisQueueSizeNamespace'
}).promise();
```

And the `scaleToTrackCustomMetric` method creates an `AlarmHigh` and `AlarmLow` alarm for scale in and out respectively. That was the source of the alarm screenshot.

Comment: Maybe add the type of your `scaling` variable to the question, it will make it easier for folks to help you.

Comment: @gshpychka add type

Comment: I've removed my answer as it was not fully correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you aren't seeing it in the CDK but you *are* seeing it in the console is because the console tends to merge multiple different types of resources together to make it easier to start.

Specifically, the resource you're looking for is creating a cloudwatch *alarm*, and you can see the CDK information for this construct here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch.Alarm.html which contains the `datapointsToAlarm` attribute. So you'll end up creating a cloudwatch custom metric (which you've already done), then add an alarm to that metric (which you're missing).

That having been said, as you've mentioned, target scaling is meant to be more managed so you don't *need* alarms. You're already telling your service to create or destroy instances to meet a given threshold (presumably 10k, given the name of the policy). The way to control how often it does that is not to control the data points you need to hit, but to control the scale-out and in cooldowns that you already have set up in your configuration. For example, if you're sending data every 30 seconds, and you want a minimum of 2 data points, you'd set your scale out cooldown to 60 seconds. It will be a little more aggressive to scale out the first time, but it will wait for two 30-second data points before it scales out every time after. Adding an alarm to the metric will let you alert someone when the metric goes out of bounds, but it won't impact your target scaling.

To your question about manually decreasing the task quantity, it's possible but there are a *lot* of race conditions. The order in which you call the API can have various impacts on your application:

- If you call `update_service` first to decrease your task size, then exit the container on a task, it's possible that the ecs-agent will issue a kill command against a *different* application instance, and you will scale down 2 instances (one killed by the ecs agent and one that you manually shut down) instead of 1. This might be OK, because the second application instance will immediately restart, however if that shuts down to 0 instances that's likely a problem.
- If you call `stop_task` before you call update_service, it's possible the ecs-agent will restart a task instance because it believes it still needs to match the desired instances. When you call `update_service`, it may terminate a different instance since it's now "+1" from where it thinks it should be.

You can still do this if you want, and you can user termination protection to stop the race conditions. In general though, I would view both of these solutions as a "last ditch" measure; try to avoid doing them and just let normal autoscaling handle your scale-out/in needs.

Comment: You mention that I'm missing the alarm connected to the custom metric. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but the high and low alarms that are created by the cdk code above are connected and go into alarm when the thresholds are crossed. In any case, it seems like the cooldown periods are analogous to the datapoints to alarm setting I was inquiring about?

Comment: Correct, the cooldown period is what you're looking for to determine how often to scale. I'm not completely sure why the CDK would create a high and low threshold alarm when you apply a tracking policy, it may be an artifact of when stepScaling was the only scaling option. If you want to control the attributes of an alarm (such as the data point to alarm) you'd have to create one directly in the CDK.

Comment: @Patrick this is not entirely correct - apparently the target tracking policy creates an Alarm automatically, and that's what controls the scaling. Creating a new Alarm wouldn't do anything here.

Comment: I agree that creating a new metric wouldn't do anything - the target scaling is controlled by the created scaling policy; I was just noting that you couldn't manage information about a metric not created by the CDK. Poor wording on my part, sorry about that.